# Error Publishing with /p:PublishSingleFile=true Flag with .NET Core 3.1 WPF project

Tags: wpf, .net-core-3.1, dotnet-publish

I have a .NET Core 3.1 WPF Project.

I get this error - what does the "with the same BundleRelativePath" mean?

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.300-preview.23122.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(917,5): error MSB4018:
> “GenerateBundle”任务意外失败。
> [E:\Solutions\087ReagentBox\87VS\JDNetCore.WPF87\JDNetCore.WPF87.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.300-preview.23122.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(917,5):
>
> Error MSB4018:
> System.ArgumentException: Invalid input specification:
> Found entries
> 'C:\Users\Andy\.nuget\packages\microsoft.toolkit.win32.ui.xamlapplication\6.1.2\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.xml' and
> 'C:\Users\Andy\.nuget\packages\microsoft.toolkit.win32.ui.xamlapplication\6.1.2\build\..\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.xml'
> with the same BundleRelativePath 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.xml'
> [E:\Solutions\087ReagentBox\87VS\JDNetCore.WPF87\JDNetCore.WPF87.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.300-preview.23122.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(917,5):   > error MSB4018:
>
> at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.Bundle.Bundler.GenerateBundle(IReadOnlyList`1 fileSpecs) [E:\Solutions\087ReagentBox\87VS\JDNetCore.WPF87\JDNetCore.WPF87.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.300-preview.23122.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(917,5):   > error MSB4018:
> at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateBundle.ExecuteCore()
> [E:\Solutions\087ReagentBox\87VS\JDNetCore.WPF87\JDNetCore.WPF87.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.300-preview.23122.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(917,5): error MSB4018:
> at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
> [E:\Solutions\087ReagentBox\87VS\JDNetCore.WPF87\JDNetCore.WPF87.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.300-preview.23122.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(917,5): error MSB4018:
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> [E:\Solutions\087ReagentBox\87VS\JDNetCore.WPF87\JDNetCore.WPF87.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.300-preview.23122.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(917,5): error MSB4018:
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask)
> [E:\Solutions\087ReagentBox\87VS\JDNetCore.WPF87\JDNetCore.WPF87.csproj]

This is my project info:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <WebView2UseWinRT>False</WebView2UseWinRT>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <Authors>Andy</Authors>
    <RepositoryUrl />
    <PackageProjectUrl></PackageProjectUrl>
    <Copyright>Copyright © JDNetCmp 2018-2025</Copyright>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64;x86</Platforms>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ApplicationIcon>Resources\Img\icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <UseWindowsForms>True</UseWindowsForms>
    <StartupObject>JDNetCore.WPF87.App</StartupObject>
    <Company>JDNet</Company>
    <Product>试剂管理平台</Product>
    <PackageIcon>logo.png</PackageIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="app.manifest" />
    <None Remove="background.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\fonts\digital_display.ttf" />
    <None Remove="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-BOLD.OTF" />
    <None Remove="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-EXTRALIGHT.OTF" />
    <None Remove="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-HEAVY.OTF" />
    <None Remove="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-LIGHT.OTF" />
    <None Remove="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-MEDIUM.OTF" />
    <None Remove="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-NORMAL.OTF" />
    <None Remove="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-REGULAR.OTF" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\back.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\background.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\borrow.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\card.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\check.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\close.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\in.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\logoff.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\logo_name.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\offline.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\online.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\out.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\qrcode.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\query.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\record.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\repay.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ImgV2\userlight.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\andyface.jpg" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\background.jpg" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\background.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\balance.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\balanceIcon.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\bgqrcode.jpg" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\borrow.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\check.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\cover.jpg" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\Cover.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\edit.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\error.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\fatial.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\in.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\info.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\nocard.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\nodata.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\offline.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\online.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\out.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\pan.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\qr.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\qrcode.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\query.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\record.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\repay.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\success.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Img\warn.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\SIMSUN.TTC" />
    <None Remove="UserControl\Pan\back.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\back.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\borrow.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\card.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\check.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\close.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\in.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\logoff.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\logo_name.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\offline.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Emgu.CV.Bitmap" Version="4.6.0.5131" />
    <PackageReference Include="Emgu.CV.runtime.windows" Version="4.6.0.5131" />
    <PackageReference Include="HandyControl" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost" Version="6.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.WebView2" Version="1.0.1462.37" />
    <PackageReference Include="MvvmLightLibsStd10" Version="5.4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="QRCoder" Version="1.4.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="squirrel.windows" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ViewFaceCore" Version="0.3.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="ViewFaceCore.all_models" Version="6.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="ViewFaceCore.Extension.SystemDrawing" Version="0.3.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="ViewFaceCore.runtime.win.vc" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ViewFaceCore.runtime.win.x64" Version="6.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="ViewFaceCore.runtime.win.x86" Version="6.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net" Version="0.16.9" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JDNetCore.Common\JDNetCore.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JDNetCore.Entity\JDNetCore.Entity.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JDNetCore.Model\JDNetCore.Model.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="background.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\fonts\digital_display.ttf" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-BOLD.OTF" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-EXTRALIGHT.OTF" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-HEAVY.OTF" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-LIGHT.OTF" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-MEDIUM.OTF" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-NORMAL.OTF" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\fonts\SOURCEHANSANSCN-REGULAR.OTF" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\background.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\online.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\out.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\qrcode.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\query.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\record.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\repay.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\userlight.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\andyface.jpg" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\balance.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ImgV2\balance.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\bgqrcode.jpg" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\borrow.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\check.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\cover.jpg" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\Cover.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\edit.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\error.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\fatial.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\icon.ico" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\in.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\info.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\nocard.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\nodata.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\offline.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\online.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\out.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\pan.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\qr.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\qrcode.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\query.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\record.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\repay.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\success.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\warn.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Img\yescard.png" />
    <Resource Include="UserControl\Pan\back.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Staging.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="localStorage.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="pdfium.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="RDprinter.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\Img\icon.ico">
      <Pack>True</Pack>
      <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_eye.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalcatface_extended.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_fullbody.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_licence_plate_rus_16stages.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_lowerbody.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_profileface.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_smile.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades\haarcascade_upperbody.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_eye.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_fullbody.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_lowerbody.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_profileface.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_smile.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\haarcascades_cuda\haarcascade_upperbody.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\hogcascades\hogcascade_pedestrians.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\lbpcascades\lbpcascade_frontalcatface.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\lbpcascades\lbpcascade_frontalface.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\lbpcascades\lbpcascade_frontalface_improved.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\lbpcascades\lbpcascade_profileface.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Resources\opencv\lbpcascades\lbpcascade_silverware.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Resources\opencv\" />
    <Folder Include="Window\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="UserControl\Page\CheckQuery.xaml.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I just run `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true`

I use the WPF tool *handycontrol*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.